# Retriving IGES entity 126 properties from a TopoDS_Edge object of type GeomAbs_BSplineCurve

Tags: opencascade

An IGES entity 126 has a property or flag 3 value of `0 = rational or 1 = polynomial`. After converting the entity to TopoDS_Edge, how do you retrieve the flag value? Or, if possible how do you check whether a bspline curve gives us a straight line or otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me I found the `IsRational()` function. I hope this is the proper use:

```
TopoDS_Edge edge = TopoDS::Edge(shape);
BRepAdaptor_Curve curve = BRepAdaptor_Curve(edge);
bool isrational = curve.IsRational();
```

Better solutions are still welcome. :)